# Installation Error: The remote server returned an error: (424) Method Failure

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I'm trying to install **Sitecore Experience Commerce 9.0.3** on top of **Sitecore Experience Platform 9.0.2**.

My problem is when I run the install script, I get an error at `CreateDefaultStorefront` task.

`[--- CreateDefaultStorefront : CreateDefaultStorefront ---]
Creating the default storefront...
Error occured: The remote server returned an error: (424) Method Failure....
Creating the default storefront complete...`

So at the end everything works but I have no frontstore. SXA looks like default home page. Yesterday I was able to install Sitecore Experience Commerce 9.0.2 successfully, now I can't. Anyone has faced it before? Thanks!

EDIT

Log => `PS>TerminatingError(Invoke-RestMethod): Get-Item : Cannot find path 'master:\{592E2CC0-E0C8-4FA7-AE7D-C8DDC1D37AFE}' because it does not exist.`

Search result is like below (GUID doesn't match, I didn't understand)

[image]

Comment: Is this a clean instance of XP 9.0.2 you're attempting to install against? Are you using SxA 1.8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking the version of SXA I noticed I was using 1.7.1 but it should be 1.8 (just as Rob said). Now, it's working.